# Entity Framework "FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it." error for a return object

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have this view

```
[Table("vw_Entity", Schema = "c")]
public partial class vw_Entity : BaseEntity
{
    public long? PredictedEntityTypeID { get; set; } 
    public bool IsManuallyChanged { get; set; } 
}
```

where `BaseEntity` is the class that stores only my `ID` and `UUID`.

This is my DTO return object:

```
public class EntityDTO
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public LookupTableDetails PredictedEntityTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool IsManuallyChanged { get; set; }
}
```

where `LookupTableDetails` looks like:

```
public class LookupTableDetails
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have this stored procedure that does basically a `PATCH`. I call it using the following snippet:

```
var data = await _context.vw_Entity.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE core.Update_Entity @EntityID", parameters)
                .Select(x => new EntityDTO()
                {
                    ID = x.ID,
                    PredictedEntityTypeId = new LookupTableDetails() { Id = x.PredictedEntityTypeId, Name = x.PredictedEntityTypeId == 1 ? "Entity1" : "Entity2" },
                    IsManuallyChanged = x.IsManuallyChanged
                }).ToListAsync();
```

However, this crashes with an error

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it

I'm aware what this error does, if I have a object of some other class inside my view then the stored procedure couldn't map it properly and return the error but in this case, my view is clear from obstacles of that type and all I need to do is just return the `LookupTableDetails` in my `DTO` object. The error is in

```
PredictedEntityTypeId = new LookupTableDetails() { Id = x.PredictedEntityTypeId, Name = x.PredictedEntityTypeId == 1 ? "Entity1" : "Entity2" }
```

I tried most of the solutions that the Internet offers, such as wrapping it with `IgnoreFilters..`, `AsEnumerable()` etc.

Any ideas what is the cause and how can I prevent it from happening again in the future i.e fix it? :D

Comment: *I'm aware what this error does* Are you? EF tries to translate the entire query into SQL. That requires a SQL statement that composed over a stored procedure result, which is impossible. `AsEnumerable()` should work, but you don't show how you tried it.

Comment: The `AsEnumerable()` was used just before `ToListAsync()`. The code looked like `.Select(x => ...) { ... }.AsEnumerable().ToList();`. But isn't `AsEnumerable()` a worse solution because I've read somewhere that `AsEnumerable()` will return all of the records and then I'll need to do an additional filter in my code while this procedure returns different records for different input params. Basically the code would be wrapped with many `if..else` for different input params and have many filters which in my case I'd like to avoid

Comment: Well, there's no choice. You have to execute the stored procedure as it is. `AsEnumerable()` should be added just before the `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

Since You iterate over result from the first query, try changing to:

```
var data = _context.vw_Entity.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE core.Update_Entity @EntityID", parameters)
                .ToList() // force change from IQueryable to IEnumerable and resolve result
                .Select(x => new EntityDTO()  // You are anyway using all results, so this is ok
                {
                    ID = x.ID,
                    PredictedEntityTypeId = new LookupTableDetails() { Id = x.PredictedEntityTypeId, Name = x.PredictedEntityTypeId == 1 ? "Entity1" : "Entity2" },
                    IsManuallyChanged = x.IsManuallyChanged
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `IEnumerable does not contain a definition for ToListAsync()`

Comment: oh yea, it doesn't exist sorry, was recomposing from your code, will update

Comment: Yeah, no worries, all good. Thank you for your help tho :)

Comment: @anthino12 so did it fix the problem for You, i am curious what Your issue was

Comment: No, it didn't. The problem is, my procedure returns me a `PredictedEntityTypeID` value. In this case, I try to construct the object directly in the `.Select()` and the error pops up. If I do `foreach(var d in data) { PredictedEntityTypeID = new LookupTableDetails() {Id = d.PredictedEntityTypeID..}` after this `.Select()` statement, the code works great.

Comment: @anthino12 ok, yes well :) the problem is that your IQueryable becomes part of query execution composition and your type is one that cannot be composed because it is not know inside the query engine so the solution is to break out of that before instantiating like suggested. 

You could perhaps hack it by registering a DbSet of type LookupTableDetails, set keys on that etc and id might possibly be able to compose using it