# 'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a simple stored procedure that I call the FromSqlRaw command.

```
db.Package.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.sp_GetPackage").First();
```

In this case, get me the error that :

> 'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
> Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Of course  When I changed my code to :

```
db.Package.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.sp_GetPackage").Tolist().First();
```

worked currently.

Actually, I should not use  Tolist(). Can you help me?

Comment: If `sp_GetPackage` is not Table-Values function, You can do only `db.Package.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.sp_GetPackage").AsEnumerable().First();`

Comment: OK This works fine

Comment: Side note: [don't use `sp_` prefix for stored procedures.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42640852/861716)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework "FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it." error for a return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496335/entity-framework-fromsqlraw-or-fromsqlinterpolated-was-called-with-non-composab)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not using HasQueryFilter in the entity

```
modelBuilder.Entity(type).HasQueryFilter(predicate);
```

If this is the case, use .IgnoreQueryFilters() and do this:

```
customStorage.Set<Group>().FromSqlRaw(sql, userId).IgnoreQueryFilters().ToListAsync()
```

Or
await

```
_db.RoleRecursiveDtos.FromSqlInterpolated(prCommand).IgnoreQueryFilters().ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```